# How can RPC client access span attributes/child spans created by server

Tags: python, opentracing

I'm using the Python opentracing module with an RPC (over HTTP) client.

At the moment I'm not interested in sending the tracing logs to an application like Jaeger - I just want to examine the span (and child spans) in the client when the RPC call returns.

So far I have this:

```
tracer = MockTracer()
with tracer.start_span('my-client') as span:
    span.set_tag(tags.HTTP_METHOD, 'GET')
    span.set_tag(tags.HTTP_URL, url)
    span.set_tag(tags.SPAN_KIND, tags.SPAN_KIND_RPC_CLIENT)
    opentracing.global_tracer().inject(span.context, Format.HTTP_HEADERS, headers)
    results = requests.request('GET', url, headers=headers, params=params, json=body)
# Extract from span any tags added by the server and/or any child spans created by the server???
```

I found I had to use `MockTracer()` to get anything at all. The base `Tracer()` class didn't seem to make any of the basic information (`start_time`, `finish_time`, `tags` etc) of the spans publicly accessible.

I can't currently figure out how to retrieve the updated span (in order to read any tags the server might have added) and any child spans created by the server from the results of the request. (I'm also a bit puzzled about how the server will know what kind of child spans to create - obviously they need to be the same kind as the span that is passed in through the headers.)

In a nutshell, while reporting traces to a central server like Jaeger is useful, my purpose here is to have the RPC client print out all the server's tracing information. (Not to say I don't want the traces in Jaeger as well but I'll deal with that once the client trace reporting is working.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "you can't."

My question was based on a very fundamental misunderstanding of what opentracing does.

> [Tracing context is only propagated downstream, not upstream.](https://github.com/opentracing/opentracing.io/issues/102#issuecomment-230031182)

From the same discussion thread:

> On the wire propagation is only meant to carry "span context", which
>   is a small set of ID fields and possible baggage. Returning the whole
>   trace as part of the request is not a use case that was considered.

and

> The trace collection is meant to be asynchronous and out of process.

So my understanding is now thus:

Each individual software component creates its own tracing data, bundles it up, and sends it off to the tracing server (e.g. Jaeger). Each software component **must** be configured to use the same tracing provider and the same tracing server - an RPC client cannot tell an RPC server that for a particular trace it should use the Jaeger tracing provider and a Jaeger server at such-and-such an address. (At least, the opentracing standard doesn't provide a way to do this.) The tracing information injected into a RPC request by the client allows the RPC server to embed a 'parent' ID field into the tracing information.

It's then the responsibility of the tracer (e.g. Jaeger) to figure out the relationships between the various traces it has received from various software components by matching up ID codes embedded in them.

So what I wanted to do is not a use case considered by opentracing and is not possible.